# Join two binary strings

Tags: php, sockets

I am receiving binary data with socket_recv function. Is there some way in php to merge them into one so I can still work with them as with binary strings?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating them yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply concatenate arbitrary strings with the `.` operator:

```
<?php
$s = "a\0b" . "c\0d";
var_export($s); // outputs  'a' . "\0" . 'bc' . "\0" . 'd'
```